# Run HtmlTestRunner Selenium UnitTests in Django GitLab Repository

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, gitlab, python-unittest

I have a Django Project on a GitLab repository. I've created a Test Suite using Selenium, UnitTest and HtmlTestRunner in Python. I want to automatically run the tests when pushing in GitLab. I read something about GitLab CI, but I'm not sure how this can be made.

Comment: Are you using gitlab.com, or a self-hosted instance?  How much familiarity do you have with Docker (it's pretty core to this process, unless you choose to do the automated testing on your own server)

Comment: @TimNyborg I'm using gitlab.com. The idea is to run the tests on localhost, but I'm not sure how this can be made.

Comment: You'll want to spend a _bunch_ of time reading up what Gitlab CI/CD is and how it works.  While you can install gitlab runner on your own server in order to run tests locally, you may find it simpler to use Gitlab's Docker-based runners and do it on the cloud: you can take a python image, install your repository and requirements, run the tests, and get the output.  Depending on the size/frequency of your tests, Gitlab's free tier may be enough for you.